# Column name with column caption and count / Pivot based on column label in other table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have two tables as follows:

**TABLE marklist:**

```
student_id  class_id    subject_1   subject_2   subject_3   subject_4   subject_5
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           9           78          87                                  95
2           9           67          95                                    87
3           9           85          84                                    85
4           10          70                      65          78    
5           10          75                      80          81    
6           10          80                      75          82
```

**Table subject_names**

```
column_name     subject_name
--------------- -------------
subject_1       English
subject_2       Chemistry
subject_3       Economics
subject_4       Accounts
subject_5       Biology
```

Now, I need to generate a report like this for class_id = 9

```
column_name     subject_name  no_of_students
--------------- ------------- --------------
subject_1       English       3
subject_2       Chemistry     3
subject_3       Economics     0
subject_4       Accounts      0
subject_5       Biology       3
```

In short, I have to generate a report with column_names, subject_name and the number of students from class_id = 9 (or 10, whatever) who have appeared for that subject.

All that I have managed to do is

1.

```
    SELECT sn.column_name, sn.subject_name FROM subject_names sn;
```

and

2.

```
    SELECT ml.class_id,
           count(ml.subject_1) AS s1,
           count(ml.subject_2) AS s1,
           count(ml.subject_3) AS s1,
           count(ml.subject_4) AS s1,
           count(ml.subject_5) AS s1,
      FROM marklist ml
     WHERE ml.class_id = 9;
```

I don't understand how do I go ahead and pivot the results of query 2 with query one. I may be going into the wrong direction but I don't have an idea.

Comment: In the long term, you'll likely be much better served by further normalizing your data; repeating columns is often a sign of design flaws.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse- Sometimes we all are obligated to live with things as they are without changing them, aren't we? This is one of those times for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. You can skip the CTE and check the main query out in the following:

```
/* -- This WITH clause is just for your reference.
WITH marklist AS (
SELECT 1 student_id, 9 class_id, 78 subject_1,87 subject_2,
       null subject_3, null subject_4, 95 subject_5 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 9, 67,95, null, null, 87 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 9, 85,84, null, null, 85 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 10,70, null, 65,78, null FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 10,75, null, 80,81, null FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 10,80, null, 75,82, null FROM dual
)
, subject_names AS (
SELECT 'subject_1' column_name, 'English' subject_name FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'subject_2', 'Chemistry' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'subject_3', 'Economics' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'subject_4', 'Accounts' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'subject_5', 'Biology' FROM dual
) -- */
SELECT sn.column_name, sn.subject_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(CASE sn.column_name
                        WHEN 'subject_1' THEN ml.subject_1
                        WHEN 'subject_2' THEN ml.subject_2
                        WHEN 'subject_3' THEN ml.subject_3
                        WHEN 'subject_4' THEN ml.subject_4
                        WHEN 'subject_5' THEN ml.subject_5
                      END)
           FROM marklist ml
          WHERE ml.class_id = 9) AS no_of_students
  FROM subject_names sn;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
column_name    subject_name    no_of_students
-------------- --------------- --------------
subject_1      English         3
subject_2      Chemistry       3
subject_3      Economics       0
subject_4      Accounts        0
subject_5      Biology         3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [unpivot](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) your marklist table and outer join it with subject_names table.

```
with unpivot_x(student_id,class_id,subject_code,marks) as (
    select * from marklist
    unpivot (marks for subject_code in (  subject_1 as 'subject_1',
                                          subject_2 as 'subject_2',
                                          subject_3 as 'subject_3',
                                          subject_4 as 'subject_4',
                                          subject_5 as 'subject_5'
                                      )
                                      ))
select a.column_name,a.subject_name, count(b.student_id)
  from subject_names a left outer join unpivot_x b
    on a.column_name = b.subject_code and b.class_id = 9
 group by a.column_name,a.subject_name
 order by 1;
```

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e3f8/3).

Comment: Your answer is definitely useful but I have found a solution myself much before you posted. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.column_name, a.subject_name, COUNT( subject_1 ) 
FROM subject_names a
JOIN mark_list b ON b.class_id =9
AND a.subject_name =  'English'
GROUP BY a.subject_name
UNION ALL SELECT a.column_name columnname, a.subject_name, COUNT( subject_3 ) 
FROM subject_names a
JOIN mark_list b ON b.class_id =9
AND a.subject_name =  'Chemistry'
GROUP BY a.subject_name
UNION ALL SELECT a.column_name columnname, a.subject_name, COUNT( subject_4 ) 
FROM subject_names a
JOIN mark_list b ON b.class_id =9
AND a.subject_name =  'Economics'
GROUP BY a.subject_name UNION ALL 
SELECT a.column_name columnname, a.subject_name, COUNT( subject_2 ) 
FROM subject_names a
JOIN mark_list b ON b.class_id =9
AND a.subject_name =  'Accounts'
GROUP BY a.subject_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT a.column_name columnname, a.subject_name, COUNT( subject_1 ) 
FROM subject_names a
JOIN mark_list b ON b.class_id =9
AND a.subject_name =  'Biology'
GROUP BY a.subject_name
```

Comment: How? On what basis do you say that?

Comment: Used join to retrieve the result.